# text formating to specific width

Tags: bash, printf

I wrote a script to show down- and up-speed of my notebook with polybar. The problem I run into is to put the output of `echo` in formation.

ATM my output looks like this (bash script loops in terminal) ...

```
WLAN0: ⬇️ 14 MiB/s ⬆️ 16 KiB/s
WLAN0: ⬇️ 60 B/s ⬆️ 0 B/s
WLAN0: ⬇️ 120 B/s ⬆️ 120 B/s
```

But I want it lined up, like this ...

```
WLAN0: ⬇️ 14 MiB/s  ⬆️ 16 KiB/s
WLAN0: ⬇️ 60 B/s    ⬆️ 0 B/s
WLAN0: ⬇️ 120 B/s   ⬆️ 120 B/s
```

The essence of my code is the following simplified line ...

```
echo "yada: ⬇️ $string1 ⬆️ $string2"
```

The variables include a number and text (up to 10 chars max) each, depending on transfer speed.

So there should be at least 12 static fields between the two *emoji*.
But I have no clue how and I am hoping you can explain to me how to format some kind of variables width, with `printf` I assume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Align left with `printf`:

```
string1="14 MiB/s"; string2="16 KiB/s"
printf "yada: ⬇️ %-12s ⬆️ %-12s\n" "$string1" "$string2"
```

Output:

`yada: ⬇️ 14 MiB/s     ⬆️ 16 KiB/s`

Answer (score 0):

Here you is how you can align columns:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

dnIcon=$'\342\254\207\357\270\217'
upIcon=$'\342\254\206\357\270\217'

nMiBs=14
sMiBs="$nMiBs MiB/s"

nKiBs=16
sKiBs="$nKiBs KiB/s"

printf 'WLAN0: %s  %-10s  %s  %-10s\n' "$dnIcon" "$sMiBs" "$upIcon" "$sKiBs"
```

Sample output:

```
WLAN0: ⬇️  14 MiB/s    ⬆️  16 KiB/s
```